# Bad Variable Name Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to create a script to automate the IPSEC user addition process. When I try and run the following code with 'sh user.sh'.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Tell me a name for the user"
echo "Please, use one word only, and no special characters"
read -r USER
```

I get the following response:

```
Tell me a name for the user 
Please, use one word only, and no special characters
test 
: bad variable nameSER
```

I've searched Google for the past hour, and I haven't been able to find any solution that works. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have a stray carriage return character. (Windows uses CR-LF for line endings; UNIX-like systems use just LF).

`cat -A user.sh` should show you any non-printable characters.

Comment: Very first item in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info under "Before asking about problematic code".